# libpipeline fails to compile on Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, autotools, libtool, gnulib

I am trying to build `libpipeline` on Mac OS X, but I am getting errors that I have not encountered with other programs that use `autotools`.

This is the first error I get:

```
/Developer/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .libs/libgnu.a(sig-handler.o) has no symbols
```

The second error is much more cryptic:

```
warning: /Developer/usr/bin/nm: no name list
```

Finally, I get this error, which is speculatively a culmination of the previous errors.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_program_name", referenced from:
      _error in libgnu.a(error.o)
      _error_at_line in libgnu.a(error.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Full log: https://gist.github.com/ahyattdev/7e4da95d48a6d25ad77aad926a14e7b0

Steps to reproduce: Get the source of `libpipeline 1.4.1`, run `configure; make`.

Comment: The first one is not an error, it's a simple informational message. However, as far as I know, neither `libpipeline` nor `libgnu` are supported on OS X.

Comment: `program_name` is extern symbol. Try with `CFLAGS="-Wl,-flat_namespace,-undefined,suppress"`.

Comment: Those arguments fixed this issue for me. A library specific issue was then introduced, which I fixed with a dummy header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This comment was the main contribution to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36824434/libpipeline-fails-to-compile-on-mac-os-x#comment61228212_36824434)

Configure command:

```
CFLAGS="-Wl,-flat_namespace,-undefined,suppress -Iwindows.h" ./configure
```

A few errors arise related to a header that is windows specific, but it only needs a few entries in the header to get this to compile.

Contents of windows.h (I placed it in the project root)

```
typedef intptr_t;
#define INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE -1
```

This will allow the project to successfully build.

Comment: The flags seem to confuse `configure` script. It may result in a broken binary. Try adding them to `make` command instead: `make CFLAGS="-Wl,-flat_namespace,-undefined,suppress"`.

Comment: @baf You're right in that passing those flags to `configure` confuses it and results in a broken binary. It did that for me, at least. Passing them to `make` instead seems to have fixed the issue.